# When is the ActionForm instantiated?

Tags: struts

I am using Struts 1.x for an application.

I want to know when the `ActionForm` instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionServlet` actually delegates the request processing job to it's `RequestProcessor`.

When a request arrives, either the `doGet` or the `doPost` method of the action servlet is invoked. Any of these method will call the action servlet's `process` method which inturn calls the request processor's `process` method. And that's where everything happen, roughly as follows -

1. Find the `ActionMapping` for current request.
2. Get (may be also create) the `ActionForm` instance.
3. Populate the form.
4. Validate the form.
5. Get (create) the `Action` instance.
6. Execute the action.
7. And finally either forward or redirect.

If you want (or need) to know in detail then you can always take a look at the source code. Followings are the links to the source codes for Struts 1.3.10 (you can also find sources for other versions of struts if that's not your version) -

- [`org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.10/org/apache/struts/action/ActionServlet.java#ActionServlet)
- [`org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.10/org/apache/struts/action/RequestProcessor.java#RequestProcessor)